# Importing library project in Android Studio

Tags: android, import, android-studio, library-project

I'm trying to import [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/) android library project into my application from Android Studio (0.2.5, gradle 1.7), but I always get some error, no matter what I try.

I mainly have tried to follow the most voted answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio), (I even tried with a HelloWord project from the scratch and actionbarsherlock) but at the end I get some error, like

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':libraries:actionbarsherlock'.
> Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.7
```

Can anyone help me? Can you import either the filedialog or the sherlock library into an Android studio project?

Comment: did you try with gradle 1.6 ?

Comment: "Trying with gradle 1.6" can have a lot of meanings... I've tried something, but with no results.

Comment: I mean : ensure that the gradle version used by android-studio is 1.6 instead of 1.7

Comment: I was not able to do that. Furthermore, the main project is set to 1.7, so I don't know if it's a good idea

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved upgrading to Android Studio 0.2.6. Here, the "New Module" issue has been fixed, so you can add a new library module to your project. Then, I replicated the library project into this new module (adding manually activities, files, resources...), and now I've a working gradle project.

I know this is a bit tricky, but I had to make it work!